# Explain Matlab ode45 output. Is ode45 an iterative algorithm?

Tags: matlab, ode

I tried to use ode45 to solve an equation, and get output like the following. I get the idea it is trying to estimate using nearby points (as explained here https://www.mathworks.com/videos/solving-odes-in-matlab-6-ode45-117537.html). By my understanding, it should solve the equation in one round of computation? but the output looks like ode45 is an iterative algorithm (so that it generates output that repeat the '... steps ... failed attempt ... function evaluations' over and over again)? If it is iterative, could you help give some detail or references? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: That is not the usual output of ode45. What command(s) did you use exactly? The method has 7 stages, with re-use of the last value in the next step, thus the 6*n+1 function evaluations per segment. Look up "Runge-Kutta methods" and look at some implementations of order 2 and order 4 methods to see the loop over the time array that is present everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ode45` is an iterative **adaptive** ODE solver. That is, it uses a 5th order (FSAL) method to propose the an update using some stepsize `h`. Then it does the same again, but now with a 4th order method, then it compared those two updates to one another, if the difference is less than some local tolerance, it accepts the proposed update. If the difference is larger than some local tolerance, the update is rejected and the stepsize is lowered (in some smart way).

To reduce the cost of using both a 4th and 5th order method, those two methods uses (roughly) the same function evaluations.

As for your output, it is, as also noted by @LutzL, not the standard output, which might point to an error in your code.